# Computing the stable homotopy groups of the spheres using the Adams spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres, spectral-sequences, stable-homotopy-theory

As an example of application of the Adams spectral sequence I've encountered the computation of the stable homotopy groups of the sphere. This spectral sequence says that $\textrm{Ext}^{s,t}_\mathcal{A}(H\mathbb{F}_p^*\mathbb{S}, H\mathbb{F}_p^*\mathbb{S})$ converges to $\pi_{t-s} \textrm{map}(\mathbb{S}, \mathbb{S})$, where $\textrm{map}(E,F)$ denotes the spectrum $\{\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Sp}}(E, \Sigma^n F)\}_{n \geq 0}$ for two spectra $E$ and $F$.

It is claimed that $H \mathbb{F}_p^* \mathbb{S} = \mathbb{F}_p$ and $\pi_{t-s}\textrm{map}(\mathbb{S}, \mathbb{S}) = \pi_{t-s}^S$, the stable homotopy groups of the spheres.

I would appreciate if someone could explain why these two equalities hold. I'm more or less familiarized with the language of the infinity-category of spectra.

Comment: $H\mathbb{F}_p \mathbb{S}$ is just the homotopy groups of $H\mathbb{F}_p$, which is $\mathbb{F}_p$ (almost tautologically, depending on your definition).  And for the second question, $\pi_* \operatorname{map}(\mathbb{S}, \mathbb{S})$ can be taken as a definition of $\pi_*^S$, so I think you have to be clearer about what's confusing you.

Comment: @JHF For me, $H\mathbb{F}_p E$ denotes the $H \mathbb{F}_p$-cohomology of $E$, which is $H\mathbb{F}_p^n(E) := \pi_{-n} \textrm{map}(E, H\mathbb{F}_p)$. Also, my definition of stable homotopy group is $\pi_n^S := \textrm{colim}_k \pi_{n+k}(S^k)$. As you said, both equalities are probably tautological, but I can't figure them out.

Comment: It would be better to use the notation $H\mathbb{F}_p^*\mathbb{S}$, for example to distinguish it from $(H\mathbb{F}_p)_*\mathbb{S}$. (Your notation $H\mathbb{F}_p\mathbb{S}$ could be either, it is ambiguous at best.)

Comment: Part of the setup for a category of spectra is a connection with topological spaces. Adams does that for the homotopy category of spectra in his blue book. How does this work in your setup? What references are you using for the infinity category of spectra?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks, I'm changing it now. I'm following Denis Nardin's lectures: https://homepages.uni-regensburg.de/~nad22969/stable-homotopy-theory2020.php

Comment: Definition 2.21 in Nardin's lecture notes seems to be helpful.